# Rescale second vector by normalization transformation of first

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

First post, let's hope you don't laugh.

I have a program that does 1,000 trials to calculate two values, a score and the std deviation of that score.

So now I have two columns of values

The first column ranges from about 1.4 to -0.8 and the second standard deviation column is generally between 0.08 and 0.3

I want to normalize scores to fall between 0 and 1.  There are formulas on the net to do this and it's easy.

My question is, how can I also scale the stddev column in the exact same way so that I don't have to recalculate them?

Comment: I think the answer is just divide the stddev by the same denominator used in the score column.  Can I have someone verify this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose the first column $X_i$ has $\max_i(X_i)=1.4$ and $\min_i(X_i)=-0.8$.  Then $Y_i = \dfrac{X_i-\min(X_i)}{\max(X_i)-\min(X_i) }=  \dfrac{X_i+0.8}{2.2}$ is distributed in the range $[0,1].$

Let's call the terms of the second column $\sigma_{X_i}$.  Then the same scaling will sugest you may want to have  $\sigma_{Y_i} = \dfrac{\sigma_{X_i}}{\max(X_i)-\min(X_i) }=  \dfrac{\sigma_{X_i}}{2.2}.$

You do not need to worry about the consistent translation in $X_i$: this does not affect the standard deviation.  The standard deviation is proportion to a consistent scale factor.